# How to configure user_friends in facebook app scope?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I set user_friends in my scopes permission in App Admin but when I check on debug does not appear and don't work on my app too.

Facebook Debug:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken?q=CAAUmV9ZC6W1kBAIhAUJFVQ64ArT25JlIPDGyCCpZAx4VUvHqpOnPBaSEsn7wY0GZCczcT9YDE3C8kSHQu5xqJKFra9VlNk7opmuMa2FARetRYBfntcZB8BlKT0YiEGTqI3fVeJG39fz5PmEoSBpZCKzk6xZBknlZAAgYHRUVhczxtsahXFevI5rKIbNm7Yk0KLYjUrcyxpAEgZDZD&version=v2.0

Token:

```
CAAUmV9ZC6W1kBAIhAUJFVQ64ArT25JlIPDGyCCpZAx4VUvHqpOnPBaSEsn7wY0GZCczcT9YDE3C8kSHQu5xqJKFra9VlNk7opmuMa2FARetRYBfntcZB8BlKT0YiEGTqI3fVeJG39fz5PmEoSBpZCKzk6xZBknlZAAgYHRUVhczxtsahXFevI5rKIbNm7Yk0KLYjUrcyxpAEgZDZD
```

Comment: Did a popup show where you had to accept that the app get that permission?

Comment: Please never show any real Access Tokens here, because this can be a security risk for the respective User's account!

Answer (score 1):

If you created your app after May 1st on facebook developer portal, you will be restricted to using the newer V2 API.

In the new API, you can no longer get a list of all facebook friends for a user. You can only get friends who are also registered with your application. So if you have no friends on facebook, that are registered on your app through facebook login/oauth, you will get an empty response.

Comment: Oh! Really? How suppose I do a invite action, to invite my facebook friends to my app?

Comment: You have to have a canvas application in order to invite friends. Without a canvas app, your app can only see friends that are also registered on your app. Facebook has locked down its privacy quite a lot in the new API. If you have a canvas application, lookup the "Invitables API" in the dev docs on Facebook. If you don't have a canvas app, you'll have to live without the feature.